# get a value from SQL and put it into HTML using node.js and express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am new to web development and I am struggling with showing content from sql to HTML.

I am using Node.js , Express and SQLite3 , A folder named public with HTML ,CSS , and JS file .

So I am trying to get a value from the database which is variable ,and want to display it on my HTML page .

Below the server.js code :

```
app.get('/quotes', function(request, response){
db.all('SELECT DISTINCT hourlyrate FROM rates WHERE ratename= "fist hour" ', function 
    processRows(err, rows){
    for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        console.log(rows[i].rates);
    }
    response.json(rows);
   });
 });
```

As a result  to this I get

```
[{"hourlyrate":"1"}]
```

All I need is that "1" number and put it as a variable inside the index.html file . Below for example :

`<h1 id="Place"> Places de parking disponible niveau -1 : **THAT VALUE HERE**</h1>`

How can I do it ? is this done on the server side like I did or it could be done differently ?

Thank you

Comment: I presume you're using Ajax to get this result? Show how you're requesting this route

Comment: No I am not using ajax . Should I ?  I just type into the browser http://localhost:3000/quotes and I get my result . I want to be able to get that result but inside the HTML file . ( Updated with that value )

Comment: In this case you should as hitting that endpoint directly just returns the data you want to put on your page. See [the docs for fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started), such as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), to hit the route you've set up. You can embed ajax calls in your html that will make async calls to the db and you'll get the response as a variable.